# Error while inheriting textbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am working on one assignment to Create a user control inheriting a text box which would allow only capital alphabets. i am still working with it. below is the code which i have worked till now.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Controls

Partial Public Class textboxupper_uc

 Inherits TextBox

    Dim strUpperText As String

    Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Public Property uppText As String
        Get
            Return strUpperText
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            strUpperText = value.ToUpper
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

the line Inherits TextBox giving error as "Base class "TextBox" specified for class 'textboxupper_uc' can not be different from the base class 'user control' of one of its other partial types."

Comment: Given that this is an assignment, I guess you have to do what it says.  The things is though, you can simply set the `CharacterCasing` property of a standard `TextBox` to `Upper` and then anything typed in will be displayed in upper-case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand the difference between a user control and a custom control.  If you want to inherit the `TextBox` class then that is a custom control.  A user control is literally a class that inherits `UserControl`.

If you added a user control to your project then you have two code files containing partial classes.  The designer code file contains `Inherits UserControl` and that's why you get that error message.  Your class cannot inherit both `UserControl` and `TextBox`.

You don't actually want a user control so delete that item from the Solution Explorer.  You want a custom control, you should add a class item to your project rather than a user control.  In the class definition in the single code file, you can then add `Inherits TextBox` and you're good to go.